# Doctrine - don't add entity to a relation if it already exists in it

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entites in a ManyToOne relationship:

```
A *-->1 B
```

B has a function:

```
public addA(A $item) {
    $this->As[] = $item
}
```

the problem is that it is possible to add the same instance of A several times to an instane of B, and doing so even one extra time results in a primary key constraint error in the join table.

I know that I could solve this by simply checking if the A instance is already bound to the instance of B before adding it, but is there any way to achieve this same functionality natively in Doctrine? I.e., can I get doctrine to ignore an insertion if it would lead to a duplicate value in a relation?

Answer (score 0):

[Doctrine's indexed associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html) allow you to index a relationship array by primary key, which will guarantee that you won't end up with duplicates when you're adding items.

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="B", indexBy="primary_key_of_a")
 **/
private $As;

public addA(A $item) {
    $this->As[$item->getPrimaryKey()] = $item
}
```

**Update**

Although the answer above will guarantee that each relation will exist only once, doctrine may delete/reinsert an existing relation depending on how it was added. For more info on how to make doctrine add/delete relations to/from the db only as needed see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24358088/3574819).