# Update many-to-many association doctrine2

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine-orm, crud

Is there any solution to do this automatically?

My two entities:

```
class User
{
    /* *
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="users")
    * @JoinTable(name="user_product",
    *  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="idUser")},
    * inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="idProduct")}
    * 
    * )
    */
protected $products;
}

class Product {
    /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="products")
    */
protected $users;
}
```

**User** entity exists with two **Products** already associated ids (`1`, `2`):

```
$user = $entityManager->find('User', 1);
```

This array came from view with new **Products** data to be inserted, deleted or if already in list do nothing:

```
$array = array(1, 3, 4);
```

In this case:

```
1 = Already in association with User (do nothing)
2 = not in array and should be deleted
3 = should be inserted
4 = should be inserted
```

How to do this in doctrine2? Is there a merge function that do it automatically or shoud I do it manually?

Comment: **Answer**: Please refer to the answer I made on http://stackoverflow.com/a/35445060/2423563

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the following code

```
$user = $entityManager->find('User', 1);
$products = array();

foreach(array(1, 3, 4) as $product_id) {
    $products[$product_id] = $entityManager->getReference('MyBundle\Entity\Product', $product_id);
}

$user->setProducts($products);    
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

And `setProducts` defined as

```
function setProducts($products) {
  $this->products = new ArrayCollection($products);
}
```

In this case doctrine will delete all the user's product associations and then insert each product association passed in from the view.

I tested this on my system where a `visit` entity is associated to many `visit_tag` entities. Note that doctrine deletes all `visit_tag` associations for a given `visit` object in profiler screenshot below and then creates each one.

[image]

In order to have doctrine only delete/insert associations as needed, you have to manually merge the existing `$user->products ArrayCollection` instead of overwriting it like above. And you can do this efficiently using [indexed associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html) via the `indexBy` annotation, which lets you search/add/remove associations by a unique key (i.e. product id) in constant time.

```
class User
{
   /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="users", indexBy="id")
    * @JoinTable(name="user_product",
    *  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="idUser")},
    * inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="idProduct")}
    * )
    */
    protected $products;

    public function setProducts($products) {
        foreach($this->products as $id => $product) {
            if(!isset($products[$id])) {
                //remove from old because it doesn't exist in new
                $this->products->remove($id);
            }
            else {
                //the product already exists do not overwrite
                unset($products[$id]);
            }
        }

        //add products that exist in new but not in old
        foreach($products as $id => $product) {
            $this->products[$id] = $product;
        }    
    }
}
```

Now the profiler shows that doctrine only deletes specific associations (instead of all) and only inserts new associations.

[image]

However, in order to do the manual merge doctrine queries the db for all associations, which you would not have to do otherwise. In a nutshell:

Method 1

1. Delete all associations
2. Insert all associations passed in from view

Method 2

1. Select all associations
2. Delete only those associations that do not exist anymore
3. Insert only those associations from the view that did not exist before

Method 2 is better when the # of associations changed is relatively small compared to the total # of associations. However if you're changing most of your associations, Method 1 seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, its what a want. I think this is good to have in core doctrine2, what do you think?

Comment: what tool did you use to see this queries running?